# What is the best strategy of creating code first database with inherited entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

For example if I have a model:

```
public class BasePolicy {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
}

public class PaymentPolicy : BasePolicy {
    public string PaymentMethod  { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnPolicy : BasePolicy {
    public int ReturnTerm  { get; set; }
}
```

... and want to create codefirst database and a repository with next requirements:

- ability to retrieve base entities by `Id` in base type (`BasePolicy`). This is necessary for admin index page which displays list of policies only by it's name.
- I need to have access to children specific properties (`PaymentMethod` if it is `PaymentPolicy` - etc.) using select by `Id` . This is necessary for edit actions.

What is the best way to do that? Should I **create seperate table for each child type**?

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<PaymentPolicy> PaymentPolicies { get; set; }
     public DbSet<ReturnPolicy> ReturnPolicies { get; set; }
}
```

**+** data is logically sorted
**-** I will not be able to get `BasePolicy` entity by it's unique id without joining those tables and specifying policy type in select query. That's why I should inject some `PolicyType` enum to base type and implement repository method which will get `BasePolicy` by it's type (to determine which table to get from) and only then by unique `Id` - and downcast `BasePolicy` to specific child type policy. This is the solution I'm using just now.

... should I **remove inheritance at all**?

```
public class PaymentPolicy {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; } 
     public string PaymentMethod  { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnPolicy {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int ReturnTerm  { get; set; }
}
```

**+** data is still logically sorted
**-** I still will not be able to get `BasePolicy` entity by it's unique id.

... should I add **child types as navigation properties to base type**?

```
public class BasePolicy {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public PaymentPolicy PaymentPolicy { get; set; }
    public ReturnPolicy ReturnPolicy { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentPolicy {
    public string PaymentMethod  { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnPolicy {
    public int ReturnTerm  { get; set; }
}
```

**-** This will destroy logic model structure
**+** I will be able to get list of policies without redundant joins
**+** It will provide strong one to one relationship

Or are there some **more advanced strategies and techniques**?